# how to store the userid in the session variable for newly created user after registration

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a problem in fetching the value from the `userid` column of MySql table and storing it in session.

Here is the problem in detail:

I have a database with many tables but lets consider 2 for now.

Table name **login**:

```
| userid | username | password
```

Table name **person_details**:

```
| firstname | lastname | dob
```

Other than this i have (consider) 2 pages with 2 forms (1 at each page);

One for login and other for details after login.

My `person_details` table's `userid` is foreign key to `login` table.

what i want is when an user register, the provided `username` and `password` should be saved in the `login` table with an unique(autogenerated) `userid` which is currently working fine.*

Now the problem is in this part; when the user is registered then he/she is directed to `person_details` form and on clicking submit after filling out the form, the data should save to `person_details` table **with the same 'userid' as in 'login' table**.

```
In order to do that I think i have to store the 'userid' in the session variable so that it can be used as a parameter while inserting the value to 'person_details' table but i am not able to pass that value.
```

here is my code:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "login")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO secure_login (username, password) VALUES (%s, %s)", GetSQLValueString($_POST['username'], "text"), GetSQLValueString($_POST['password'], "text"));

mysql_select_db($database_mydatabase, $mydatabase);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $mydatabase) or die(mysql_error());
$obj = @mysql_fetch_object($Result1);
$_SESSION['userID']=$obj->userid;
```

i tried this too but no luck

```
    mysql_select_db($database_mydatabase, $mydatabase);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $mydatabase) or die(mysql_error());
$_SESSION['userID']=$Result1->userid;
```

This is the error i am getting when trying:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydatabase`.`personaldetails`, CONSTRAINT `personaldetails_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `secure_login` (`userid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

and i tried it without session and it was ok, data was saved to the table `person_details` with autogenerated `userid`.

Please let me know if u need anymore of the code or any other information.

**EDIT** I got the userID in session variable, so half of my problem is solved. Now all i need to do is to set the same userid for person_details.

P.S. When i posted this question here, i expected an answer but all i got was some visits and a fellow doing some editing for me (which i think he enjoyed so much that he edited some of my comments as code) anyways, thank you friend.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to understand, and your edit claiming to have solved half of the problem does not clear up the issue much. Here are a few suggestions:

1. Stop using mysql_ and start using mysqli_
2. I do not believe you will be able to successfully capture any items as a result from an insert
3. You need to enumerate the values you are inserting if they are not being inserted in the exact order they occur in the target table.

   ```
   INSERT INTO person_details(firstname, lastname, dob, userid) VALUES('firstname', 'lastname', 'dob', 'userid');
   ```

Comment: first of all, thank you for your reply. secondly, i would like to know, that ur suggestion to use mysqli instead of mysql is just for best practice or will it help my problem. and am not capturing anything using insert, i used    $_SESSION['userID'] = mysql_insert_id(); to get the userID from the table. other than that, i am using the correct order for this and am sure of that as it is working fine if i skip userID for second table. I am trying to explain it as much as possible but the problem itself is a little complicated.

Comment: The mysql extension is deprecated, so you should never use it over mysqli. It has string escape issues and persistent connection problems in later versions of MySQL.